# R: calculate groupwise means with overlapping groups

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I have the following table with sample data:

```r
set.seed(10)
dat <- data.frame(grp1 = sample(c(0, 1), size = 5, replace = TRUE),
                   grp2 = sample(c(0, 1), size = 5, replace = TRUE),
                   grp3 = sample(c(0, 1), size = 5, replace = TRUE),
                   value = round(runif(5, min = 0, max = 10), 0) )
dat
  grp1 grp2 grp3 value
1    0    0    0     4
2    0    1    1     1
3    1    1    0     3
4    1    0    0     4
5    1    0    1     8
```

But in the end, I need a tibble like this:

```
group              mean
-----------------------
grp1                5.0    
grp2                2.0
grp3                4.5
```

Usually, I would do a `pivot_longer(cols = starts_with("grp"))`, so I could easily `group_by(name)` and calculate the groupwise means using `summarise(mean = mean(value, na.rm=TRUE))`. But here my problem is, that each of the 5 elements can belong to multiple groups (grp1, grp2, grp3), so there's some overlapping between the groups. My naive attempt would be to calculate the means for each group separately and then `rbind()` them. But as the number of groups increases this gets annoying, so I am looking for a way to automate this.

Comment: Can you develop how you compute the mean, say for group1?

Comment: Can you explain how you got those means? Why is `grp1` mean = 5?

Comment: Group 1:  (3 + 4 + 8) / 3 = 5. Actually, it's like filtering for all the grp1 cases and calculate the mean value of the variable `value`

Answer (score 4):

An idea can be,

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

dat %>% 
 pivot_longer(grp1:grp3, names_repair = 'unique') %>% 
 filter(value...3 == 1) %>% 
 group_by(name) %>% 
 summarise(means = mean(value...1))

New names:
* value -> value...1
* value -> value...3
# A tibble: 3 x 2
  name             means
  <chr>             <dbl>
1 grp1                5  
2 grp2                2  
3 grp3                4.5
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is one option. The solution is mainly based on base R. I only created a `tibble` using `dplyr` in the end.

```
library(dplyr)

dat2 <- dat[, -ncol(dat)] * dat[, ncol(dat)]

dat3 <- sapply(dat2, function(x) mean(x[x != 0]))

dat4 <- tibble(
  group = names(dat3),
  mean = dat3
)

dat4
# # A tibble: 3 x 2
#   group  mean
#   <chr> <dbl>
# 1 grp1    5  
# 2 grp2    2  
# 3 grp3    4.5
```

Comment: The multiplication is a great idea. I would make it a bit more generic though. Maybe multiply the last column with all others

Comment: @Sotos Thanks. Please see my updates. Is there a more concise way to specify the multiplication between the last row with others?

Comment: I think the way you did it is the best

Answer (score 3):

```r
colSums(dat$value * dat[-ncol(dat)]) / colSums(dat[-ncol(dat)])
data.frame(grp = names(d), mean = unname(d))

#   grp mean
#1 grp1  5.0
#2 grp2  2.0
#3 grp3  4.5
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `base R`

```
stack(colMeans(replace(dat[-4], dat[-4] == 0, NA) * dat$value, na.rm = TRUE))[2:1]
   ind values
1 grp1    5.0
2 grp2    2.0
3 grp3    4.5
```

Answer (score 1):

Another base R option (similar to [the answer by @akrun](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72292548/12158757))

```
> rev(stack(colMeans((NA^(1 - dat[startsWith(names(dat), "grp")])) * dat$value, na.rm = TRUE)))
   ind values
1 grp1    5.0
2 grp2    2.0
3 grp3    4.
```